# NoMethodError in Devise [Registrations & Sessions] undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Showing ...views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
```

It is exactly the same case in `Registrations`, and at **all** devise routes we had configured in fact.

It's not clear which recent change brought this on.

We've tried:
*

- List item
- db:reset
- reinstalling devise
- completely rebuilding all devise models and routes and tables

It's always the same error:

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

Other questions on stackoverflow seem to be for other methods, e.g. `[]`, `new`, `authorize`... new for nil is the only one we're getting. Any ideas much appreciated.

EDITS

user.rb (model)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,   :trackable, :validatable

has_many :journeys  # n.b: must pluralize here.
end
```

routes (user routes)

```
user_registration_path   POST    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#create
PATCH    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
PUT  /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
DELETE   /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#destroy
users_path   GET     /users(.:format)    users#index
POST     /users(.:format)    users#create
```

routes.rb
    devise_for :admins
    devise_for :users
    resources :users

```
get 'journeys', to: 'users#journeys'
resources :journeys

root to: "static#index"

get '/journey/new', to: 'journeys#new'    # For some reason "resources :journeys"  isn't activating the new method.

get '/admins/add_admin', to: 'admins#add_admin'

devise_scope :user do
  get 'users/sign_out', to: 'session#destroy'
  # Don't need to define sign_in here, because it works already (unlike admin).
end

devise_scope :admin do 
  get 'admins/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  get 'admins/sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

Comment: Can you show your devise route and the model you use for the scope?

Comment: I've added the code I think you asked for, if you need more let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added the gem:
`'google_directions'` recently, it appears to be that that's what caused the issue.

It requires `'extlib/hash'` and for some reason this didn't play nice with `devise`.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a version of google_directions that is compatible with Devise: https://github.com/calebhaye/google-directions-ruby

Comment: Ha! Cheers mate. Could have done with that a few months ago :) what a pain this was. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to you application helper

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```